# Drop down menu keeps jumping to the right

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, center, centering

Some how my drop down menu keeps jumping to the right instead of dropping down right underneath it's parent.
I've tried positioning it but that doesn't work since the position changes when the browserwindow changes size.

How do I get my drop down menu centered underneath the parent?

Html:

```
<div id="topnav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="over ons.html">OVER ONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="gedragsbeinvloeding.html">GEDRAGSBEINVLOEDING</a></li>
        <li><a href="onze diensten.html">ONZE DIENSTEN</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="topmargin"><a href="onderzoek.html">ONDERZOEK</a></li>
                <li><a href="advies.html">ADVIES</a></li>
                <li><a href="lezingen.html">LEZINGEN</a></li>
            </ul>                       
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#topnav     { z-index:3;
                padding-top:76px; }

#topnav ul li   { list-style-type:none;
                display:inline;
                float:right;
                }


#topnav ul li a { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size:13px;
                font-weight:bold;
                text-decoration:none;
                padding-left:15px;
                }

#topnav ul li a:link    { color:#00aeef; }
#topnav ul li a:visited { color:#00aeef; }
#topnav ul li a:active  { color:#f26532; }
#topnav ul li a:hover   { color:#f26532; }
#topnav ul li a:focus   { color:#f26532; }

#topnav li ul       { position:absolute;
                    left:-999em;
                    list-style-type:none;
                    }

#topnav li ul li        { border-top:0px;
                    clear:both;}

#topnav li:hover ul     { left:auto; }

#topnav li:hover ul li  { float:none;
                    display:block;
                    width:100%;
                    }

#topnav ul li ul li     { text-align:center;
                    padding:10px 12px 10px 0px;
                    border-top:#FFF solid;
                    background-color:#00aeef;
                    width:120px;
                    }

.topmargin          { margin-top:5px; }

#topnav li ul li a      { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    font-size:13px;
                    font-weight:bold;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    padding-left:14px;
                    }

#topnav li ul li a:link { color:#FFF; }
#topnav li ul li a:visited  { color:#FFF; }
#topnav li ul li a:active   { color:#FFF; }
#topnav li ul li a:hover    { color:#f26532; }
#topnav li ul li a:focus    { color:#FFF; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this in or change your css

```
#topnav li:hover ul {
left: auto;
margin-left: -30px;
}
```

or

```
#topnav li ul {
left: auto;
list-style-type: none;
position: absolute;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: That did it (the margin one), thank you so much for you quick help!

Answer (score 1):

Change #topnav id to this

`#topnav{`
`z-index:3;`
             `padding-top:76px;`
                `width:800px;`

`and add the folling id`
`#topnav ul{`
    `float:left;`
`}`

`#topnav li:hover ul`
    `{left:80px;}`

Answer (score 0):

Your nested `ul` tag seems to have some unnecessary padding applied by the user-agent stylesheet.

Try using:

```
#topnav li ul {padding: 0px;}
```

This way the padding of only the nested `ul` element will be affected.